# js test if clicked element is child/descendent of

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to test if a click is on an element within a specific hierarchy.

Using:

```
var elements = parentElement.getElementsByTagName("*");
```

I  can put all elements into array, but then I can't get the test right:

```
function isClicked(e){
    if(elements.indexOf(e.target) != -1){
        //do something
    }
};
```

How do I do this correctly, please? Thanks...

(PS I am trying to create a click-away function where clicking upon anything in the body except the displayed info will close it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`Node.prototype.contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains):

```js
var button = document.querySelector('button');
var dialog = document.querySelector('.dialog');

button.addEventListener('click', function () {
  dialog.classList.add('open');
});

document.body.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  if (button !== e.target && dialog !== e.target && !dialog.contains(e.target)) {
    dialog.classList.remove('open');
  }
});
```

```css
.dialog:not(.open) {
  display: none;
}

.dialog {
  background-color: yellow;
}

span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<button>Open dialog</button>
<div class="dialog">
  <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
  <p>Hello, World! <span>Nested element<span></p>
</div>

<p>Click somewhere here to close the dialog! <span>Nested element</span></p>
```

Comment: << !dialog.contains(e.target) >> this was the snippet I needed to get everything to work correctly... turns out even easier than I was making it, no need to make an array even - thanks million Peter!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Underscore's *contains* function. So, your condition should be in that case:

```js
if (_.contains(elements, e)) {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to following:

```
function isClicked(e){
    //check e.currentTarget.children()
};
```

Comment: Since when does a `Node` have a `children` method?